# gym library env.render() Not Implemented

Tags: openai-gym

I am trying to follow a Reinforcement Learning class that is using gym and gym_ple as a framework to teach. They are using FlappyBird-v0. I am having trouble getting one segment of their code working which is collecting the rgb rendering of each frame in a list. I get the NotImplementedError error on env.render() call.

I am using
gym v: 0.25.2
gym-ple v: 0.3

```Python
!apt-get install -y xvfb
!pip install pygame pytorch-lightning==1.6.0 pyvirtualdisplay
!pip install git+https://github.com/GrupoTuring/PyGame-Learning-Environment
!pip install git+https://github.com/lusob/gym-ple

import gym
import gym_ple
from pytorch_lightning import LightningModule, Trainer
from gym.wrappers import TransformObservation

class StateVectorWrapper(gym.Wrapper):

  def __init__(self, env):
    super().__init__(env)
    state = self.reset()
    self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(
        low=float('-inf'),
        high=float('inf'),
        shape=state.shape
    )

  def reset(self):
    super().reset()
    state_dict = self.env.unwrapped.game_state.getGameState()
    state = list(state_dict.values())
    return np.array(state)

  def step(self, action):
    # ignore the next observation, which is returned as an image
    _, reward, done, info = super().step(action)
    next_state_dict = self.env.unwrapped.game_state.getGameState()
    next_state = list(next_state_dict.values())
    return np.array(next_state), reward, done, info



def create_environment(name):
  env = gym_ple.make(name)
  env = StateVectorWrapper(env)
  return env


env = create_environment('FlappyBird-v0')
print('env = ', env)
frames = []

for episodes in range(10):
  done = False
  env.reset()
  while not done:
    frames.append(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    _,_, done, _ = env.step(action)
```

```python
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-fe7207e6a2d3> in <cell line: 6>()
      9   while not done:
---> 10     frames.append(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
     11     action = env.action_space.sample()
     12     _,_, done, _ = env.step(action)

15 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gym/core.py in render(self, mode)
    224             in implementations to use the functionality of this method.
    225         """
--> 226         raise NotImplementedError
    227 
    228     def close(self):

NotImplementedError:
```

I have tried to include the render functionality inside the StateVectorWrapper by calling the appropriate render on the super class, but the gym.Wrapper class also has no render() functionality.

I also tried to pass the render_mode='rgb_array' to the make() function and it too fails with the error "render_mode" was not expected (or something to this effect).

I saw prior posts here that recommended using RecordVideo class, which has also been deprecated.

Comment: I had to go back to openai.gym version 0.9.6 (now on 26) to find a compatible version that would work with this RL class code-base !!

It would however be educational for me to know how the env.render() function is meant to be used in current versions since it is no longer implemented.

Thank you